# concrete5 loop child pages of parent

Tags: navigation, parent, concrete5

I'm new to concrete5 and need to loop out the child pages of a parent (the parent not being the current page necessarily so probably needs parent slug passing as an argument).

I'd expect this to be simple but everything I've found on it relates to autonav. I can't use the autonav due to the site navigation being in a non-standard format.

The solution doesn't need to print any markup necessarily - would be fine to just generate a PHP array of slugs and titles I can then loop into some markup. But I'll take either way :-) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thinking about it actually... it would be fine to just loop out child pages of the current page.

Answer (score 2):

If you want *some* markup, and you want this displayed on some sort of page, check out the page list block: http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/editors-guide/in-page-editing/block-areas/add-block/page-list/

If you need the pages programmatically, then there's a `PageList` model that you can pass a parent page to and get all the children as an array of `Page` objects.https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/blob/master/web/concrete/core/models/page_list.php

Answer (score 1):

I just started working with concrete 5, and I can tell this isn't optimal code. But it works, and maybe it will help you, as those other articles didn't help me too much.

That said, if you have the ID of the page you want to get sub pages for, you can do something like this:

```
$page = Page::getByID("page_id_here");
$sub_page_ids = $page->getCollectionChildrenArray(1);
foreach ($sub_page_ids as $id) {
    $page = Page::getByID($id);
    $pages_array[$page->getCollectionName()] = DIR_REL . $page->getCollectionPath();
}
```

this will output an array that looks like this

```
$pages_array["page-url-here"] = "Title of Page Here"
```

Obviously depending on what you want, you'll need to modify the code, but this is what I ended up using on my site. If anyone has suggestions on how to do grab, say, all child pages at once rather than one by one, I think that would be a lot better.